# phpmyadmin mysql docker simple link

Tags: mysql, docker, phpmyadmin

I try simple link two container in docker: phpmyadmin and mysql.
What I do:

```
$ docker run --name mysql -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=admin -d mysql    
$ docker run --name myadmin -d --link mysql:db -p 8080:80 phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin
```

But, wen login in phpmyadmin, getting an error:

```
mysqli_real_connect(): (HY000/2002): Connection refused
```

I dont want use docker-compose

Answer (score 0):

From what I have seen/read, this is because of a bug, that causes it. Try it with the mariadb container, works fine, at least for me , on Ubuntu 16.04